# Is there any documentation on what (if any) controls we have over the SDK?

Tags: android, paypal

I'm trying to make sense of what controls are exposed for the developer in PayPal's new Android SDK (it seems like just about none) and not finding much useful documentation anywhere.

So... my questions are:

**INITIAL SCREEN**

- What is the Mock Data area for... How does one put info into it and
- What sort of info would go there, or is that an indicator that this
  is a fake (mock) implementation?

**LOGIN SCREEN**

- Can I disable (or make invisible) the forgot password link?
- Can I disable (or make invisible) the Log in with Pin link?

**PAY SCREEN**

- Is it possible to disable the "Stay Logged In" toggle?
- Is it possible to NEVER keep anyone logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff here from the PayPal Mobile SDK team.  The [javadocs](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/) available on github provide fine documentation.  However, I will still address your questions here.

`Mock Data` or `Sandbox` merely indicates that this is not the live user experience.  Once you switch to `PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION`, this label will go away.

No, you cannot customize the Login Screen.

Yes, you can eliminate the "Stay Logged In" toggle by not providing a [`PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID`](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/com/paypal/android/sdk/payments/PaymentActivity.html#EXTRA_PAYER_ID).  This effectively removes any remembering.

Feel free to file issues in [GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) if you find any defects or have any feature requests!

Comment: Jeff, thanks very much. I'm not seeing a link for feature requests anywhere on the GitHub page.  Can you direct me to where in the page it's hiding? Specifically, it would be really useful to be able to get rid of the "forgot password" and "pin" links at the bottom of the login for situations where the browser is disabled and those links will simply do nothing (and confuse the end-user). What would the turn-around time be on such a request?

Comment: GitHub has an 'issues' feature.  Here is the [direct link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues).  Regarding your feature, password/pin login does not open a browser.  Forgot Password is the only browser link on the page.  It would make sense for us to customize that for a good user experience.  Please open an issue for a greater discussion!